# How to handle CNAMEs when resolving domains?

Tags: node.js, security, recursion, dns

My web application receives from untrusted user some unfiltered string, and then has to determine, if this string, when used as hostname, somehow resolves to IPv4 or IPv6 address in forbidden range, determined by set of predefined rules.

So, in case string appears to be IPv4 or IPv6 address (either canonical or not), it's simple — just translate address to whatever is it's canonical form, and test if it's in allowed ranges or not.

But what if string is valid hostname, that resolves to lot of records? Using node.js' builtin `dns` module, I get list of all DNS records for this particular hostname (`A`, `AAAA`, `TXT`, `MX`, `SRV`, `CNAME`). What next? AFAIK, `TXT`, `SRV` and `MX` do not affect name resolution at all. `A` and `AAAA` can be verified against aforementioned ruleset.

But what should I do with `CNAME`? Should I issue recursive DNS resolution for each `CNAME` encountered? Just ignore it and silently reject? If I issue recursive DNS resolution, any chance to prevent some smarthat feeding my application infinite CNAME stream, like `CNAME 1.foobar.com ⟶ CNAME 2.foobar.com ⟶ CNAME 3.foobar.com ⟶ CNAME 4.foobar.com ⟶ ...`? In case it repeats at some point, I can break out of it, but what if it does not? If I break early (after N redirections, say), hacker could forge such chain to be N+1 long, with last redirection having `A`/`AAAA` records to restricted area.

So, are there solutions to this? How do "convenient" resolvers handle this?

Comment: I wonder *what* I've been doing those years... I don't even remember any project that would require such thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I've ended setting up name server myself, and feeding it zone config similar to

```
$ORIGIN foobar.com
...
evil1 CNAME evil2.foobar.com
evil2 CNAME evil3.foobar.com
evil3 CNAME evil4.foobar.com
evil4 CNAME evil5.foobar.com
...
evil99997 CNAME evil99998.foobar.com
evil99998 CNAME evil99999.foobar.com
evil99999 CNAME evil100000.foobar.com

evil100000 A 127.12.34.56
```

---

`nslookup` request ends as follows:

```
$ nslookup evil1.foobar.com
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

evil1.foobar.com    canonical name = evil2.foobar.com.
evil2.foobar.com    canonical name = evil3.foobar.com.
evil3.foobar.com    canonical name = evil4.foobar.com.
evil4.foobar.com    canonical name = evil5.foobar.com.
evil5.foobar.com    canonical name = evil6.foobar.com.
evil6.foobar.com    canonical name = evil7.foobar.com.
evil7.foobar.com    canonical name = evil8.foobar.com.
evil8.foobar.com    canonical name = evil9.foobar.com.
evil9.foobar.com    canonical name = evil10.foobar.com.
evil10.foobar.com   canonical name = evil11.foobar.com.
evil11.foobar.com   canonical name = evil12.foobar.com.
evil12.foobar.com   canonical name = evil13.foobar.com.
evil13.foobar.com   canonical name = evil14.foobar.com.
evil14.foobar.com   canonical name = evil15.foobar.com.
evil15.foobar.com   canonical name = evil16.foobar.com.
evil16.foobar.com   canonical name = evil17.foobar.com.
evil17.foobar.com   canonical name = evil18.foobar.com.
```

---

`dig` produces similar output:

```
# dig +recurse evil1.foobar.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.23.rc1.el6_5.1 <<>> +recurse evil1.foobar.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 34317
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 17, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;evil1.foobar.com.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
evil1.foobar.com.   10  IN  CNAME   evil2.foobar.com.
evil2.foobar.com.   10  IN  CNAME   evil3.foobar.com.
evil3.foobar.com.   10  IN  CNAME   evil4.foobar.com.
evil4.foobar.com.   10  IN  CNAME   evil5.foobar.com.
evil5.foobar.com.   10  IN  CNAME   evil6.foobar.com.
evil6.foobar.com.   10  IN  CNAME   evil7.foobar.com.
evil7.foobar.com.   10  IN  CNAME   evil8.foobar.com.
evil8.foobar.com.   10  IN  CNAME   evil9.foobar.com.
evil9.foobar.com.   10  IN  CNAME   evil10.foobar.com.
evil10.foobar.com.  10  IN  CNAME   evil11.foobar.com.
evil11.foobar.com.  10  IN  CNAME   evil12.foobar.com.
evil12.foobar.com.  10  IN  CNAME   evil13.foobar.com.
evil13.foobar.com.  10  IN  CNAME   evil14.foobar.com.
evil14.foobar.com.  10  IN  CNAME   evil15.foobar.com.
evil15.foobar.com.  10  IN  CNAME   evil16.foobar.com.
evil16.foobar.com.  10  IN  CNAME   evil17.foobar.com.
evil17.foobar.com.  10  IN  CNAME   evil18.foobar.com.

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: ...
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 388
```

---

And according to tests made with plain resolvers, if `CNAME` chain does not end up with useful target after 16 hops (e.g. if 17th is still CNAME), lookup will be interrupted and domain name will be rejected as non-resolving. **CNAME attack myth busted.**

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't mess with any of this, and [leave it up to the system resolver](http://nodejs.org/api/dns.html).

```
var dns = require('dns');
dns.lookup('host.example.com');
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you? And `dns.lookup` resolves a domain into the **first found** A (IPv4) or AAAA (IPv6) record, according to docs, so it's unsafe to just say "this domain is fine", because it may eventually resolve to unsafe address.

Comment: @modchan It resolves to whatever network address your system is going to use if you're going to connect to it, which seems to be what you're looking for.  If you want to verify all the DNS records available and their network addresses, then that is a different problem.  If you want to verify that a particular DNS address will never resolve to a restricted network address than that can never be guaranteed anyway as a DNS server's response can change every request, not to mention all the other resolvers a system may use, including a simple hosts file.

Comment: "which seems to be what you're looking for" - no, I am not. I want to verify that particular DNS address won't resolve to restricted network address, and I can guarantee this, because I will resolve it only once to the full extent, and cache all the resolved addresses in my database. So it's actually important to me how `CNAME`s are handled.